# What is the use case for Access.BackingField in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automatic-properties, backing-field

The documentation for `Access.BackingField()` indicates that this:

> Sets the access-strategy to use the backing-field of an auto-property.

I understand that auto-properties get compiled with backing fields, but if the property is by definition a vanilla getter/setter, what advantage is garnered by going to the backing field directly versus using the setter (i.e. using the FNH defaults).

The only thing I can think of is that one might want the mapping to break if someone later adds logic to the setter.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, I think I found the answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/abd4c93ac820adfb).

Use the backing field if the auto-property has a `private` accessor.